# How can I get the max value of each column in a table as one row?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on a table that tracks the rent amount, and due date for a property lease. The way I'm setting the table up is that anytime the rent amount, or due date is updated, a new row is added to the table, and updates only the changed values. Unchanged values are left `NULL` in the new row. This way I can keep track of who made the change, and at what time.

What I'd like to do is grab the latest value based on the date (or ID if the date is exactly the same) it was entered, but for each column. I'm not sure if I can accomplish this using one query.

My table looks similar to this:

```
ID | Lease ID | Rent Amount | Due Date | Enter Date
------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 50019    | 900.00      | NULL     | 2017-04-01 01:00:00
2  | 50019    | 875.00      | NULL     | 2017-04-01 01:00:00
3  | 50020    | NULL        | 2        | 2017-04-02 02:00:00
4  | 50021    | 750.00      | 1        | 2017-04-03 03:00:00
5  | 50019    | NULL        | 1        | 2017-04-04 04:00:00
```

I'm looking to get the following result:

```
Lease ID | Rent Amount | Due Date
---------------------------------
50019    | 875.00      | 1
50020    | NULL        | 2
50021    | 750.00      | 1
```

Basically, for each Lease ID I would grab the absolute latest rent amount where the value is not `NULL` (will return `NULL` if there is no value), and the same with due date. Can this be accomplished using one query?

I'm stuck at the idea of it. So, unfortunately, I do not have any queries of my own to present here. If I come up with anything I will add it below.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use correlated subqueries to get the required values:

```
SELECT LeaseID, 
       (SELECT RentAmount
       FROM mytable AS t2
       WHERE t1.LeaseID = t2.LeaseID AND RentAmount IS NOT NULL
       ORDER BY EnterDate DESC, ID DESC LIMIT 1) AS RentAmount,       
       (SELECT DueDate
       FROM mytable AS t2
       WHERE t1.LeaseID = t2.LeaseID AND DueDate IS NOT NULL
       ORDER BY EnterDate DESC, ID DESC LIMIT 1) AS DueDate       
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT LeaseID
    FROM mytable) AS t1;
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/QMLA77817)

Comment: I really appreciate the fast response. This query worked perfectly, and also enlightened me on correlated subqueries. Thank you very much!